# Run-time Error 429 on Scripting.FileSystem object after scrrun.dll registered

Tags: vba, dll, excel

There are quite a few entries on here about Error Code 429, but I want to make it clear that this is a slightly different question. This is a VBA excel program.

The code causing the problem :

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim builder As String
Dim file As Object
Dim csv As Object

Set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystem")
Set csv = file.CreateTextFile("configexport.csv")
```

The program breaks on the

```
Set file = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystem")
```

I have a reference to scrrun.dll

I have registered scrrun.dll using an administrator command prompt and the command 'regsvr32 scrrun.dll'

I have restarted my computer

I am still seeing the error

NOTE: All other questions on this topic get resolved by this point so I do not consider this a duplicate. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you directly run a script that does this in VBScript and run it from a command window? Does it work from there?

Comment: What bit OS/Office (32 or 64)?

Comment: @TimWilliams OS is 64, not sure about Office

Comment: @KenWhite It failed doing it that way as, Same error message(ActiveX component can't create object), error code : 800A01AD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you meant `FileSystemObject`, and I wouldn't use **file** as your variable name:

```
Set aFile = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
```

Comment: You've got to be kidding me, this was it. I just wasted a couple hours. Thanks.

Comment: This is one reason why "early binding" can be an advantage. If that typo were made in an early binding scenario it would have failed to compile and probably highlighted the line. You could even initially test / proof of concept with early and then switch to late binding for release purposes if there is some good reason for using late in a scenario like this.